# ng serve non stop with gradle task

Tags: angular, gradle, spring-boot, angular-cli

I'm use gradle to start my app. But a i have a problem when stop my task, the  angular application non stop.

Every time i start the server the port is in use:

> Port 4200 is already in use. Use '--port' to specify a different port.

This is my build.gradle:

```
// frontend build.gradle

buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "com.moowork.gradle:gradle-node-plugin:1.1.1"
  }
}

apply plugin: "com.moowork.node"

//def generatedWebResources = "${buildDir}/generated-web-resources"

/*sourceSets {
    main {
        output.dir(generatedWebResources, builtBy: 'npm_run_build')
    }
}*/

// configure gradle-node-plugin
node {
    version = '7.5.0'
    npmVersion = '4.1.2'
    download = false
    workDir = file("${project.projectDir}/node")
    nodeModulesDir = file("${project.projectDir}/")
}

// clean node/node_modules/dist
task npmClean(type: Delete) {
    final def webDir = "${rootDir}/frontend"
    delete "${webDir}/node"
    delete "${webDir}/node_modules"
    delete "${webDir}/dist"
    delete "${webDir}/coverage"
}

// clean task for npm
task clean {}
clean.dependsOn(npmClean)

// build task for npm
task build {}
build.dependsOn(npm_install)
build.dependsOn(npm_run_build)

// assemble task for npm
task assemble {}
assemble.dependsOn(build)

// check task for npm
task check {}
check.dependsOn(npm_run_test)

// run all task
task runAll{}
runAll.dependsOn(npm_run_start)
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve --port 4200 --live-reload-port 50000 --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor",
    "build": "ng build"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-beta.31",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/moment": "2.13.0",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.3.0",
    "typescript": "~2.0.0",
    "webdriver-manager": "10.2.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you exactly start your application? What command do you use?